# How do I tell Visual Studio designer the correct title bar height for my compact framework device?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5

I am working on porting an old Compact Framework program to Intermec's CN51 hardware.  I've got a problem in that I can't get visual studio 2008 to understand that the title bar area on this OS is 36 pixels, not 52.

Total screen size is 480x800, and I am able to configure that correctly (Tools -> Options -> Device Tools -> Form Factors).  If my form is maximized, everything is fine.

If my form is not maximized, Visual Studio will set the form's Location to 0,52  -- and it's size to 480,748.

At runtime, the form is positioned only 32 pixels from the top of the screen, leaving a 16 pixel gap at the bottom.

Visual studio does not allow me to change the Location of a form.  I can change its size, but that would get blown away any time I accidentally hit the maximize property in Visual Studio.

Is there any way to configure the 'Normal' sized window in VS 2008?
[image]

Comment: Do you use the correct target platform, which is Windows Mobile (Embedded) 6.5, installed using the Windows Mobile 6.5.3 DTk (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5389)? Your emulator screen shot shows a 'old' taskbar/caption. the (X) has to be in the menu bar. See also http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2013/04/19/windows-mobile-6-5-changed-screen-geometry/

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2008 and the WM 6.5.3 DTK behave strange here. The Designer preview is incorrect but the device emulator is correct.
When you start a new project, you can select the target platform, but WM6.5.3 is not listed. You have to switch the project later on, but still get a wrong preview.
Left (or back) shows VS2008 preview and right shows the emulator.

[image: VS and emulator differences]

Possibly we will never get a consistent desginer view for that 'old' DTK.

Comment: I wonder if anyone is aware of where the designer is reading that size -- even if that meant manually editing something deep within the DTK installation.